Facing CORB issue when streaming bunny cdn video in next.js site
I'm trying to stream video in next.js site but facing CORB issue.
Error screenshot: https://cln.sh/dQ6FzX5t (https://chromestatus.com/feature/4933785622675456)
this is how I'm using it:
<video
width={600}
controls={true}
autoPlay={false}
muted={true}
loop={true}
playsInline
preload="metadata"
src={'https://video.bunnycdn.com/play/230399/cd4a6067-2792-4bea-bc19-3707307d567b'}
/>

PS: I don't want to use any iframe or embedded player and would like to use native <video/> component.
